# "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'tables_initializer' " using TFv2.2.0, Why and how to solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I got errors when I want to run these lines.

```
 import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K

 session = K.get_session()
 init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(),tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
 tf.local_variables_initializer())
 session.run(init_op)
 np.random.seed(1)
 tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

The error says: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'tables_initializer', and in the same form happens with global_variables_initializer, and local_variables_initializer (when I run them individually).

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-40-82a30eae4406> in <module>()
        5 
        6 session = K.get_session()
  ----> 7 init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(),tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
        tf.local_variables_initializer())
        8 session.run(init_op)
        9 np.random.seed(1)

        AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'tables_initializer'
```

Please, help...

Answer (score 0):

Given code is compatible with Tensorflow 1.x.
To make it work with Tensorflow 2.x, need some modification to your code, i.e.,change the library names as

> tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer()

> tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

> tf.compat.v1.local_variables_initializer().

Find the working code snippet

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np

session = K.get_session()
init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(),tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
tf.local_variables_initializer())
session.run(init_op)
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```